# Ephesoft community misses CMIS plugin

Tags: plugins, cmis, ephesoft

So I have downloaded Ephesoft Community 4.0.2.0 (http://wiki.ephesoft.com/community-edition-v4-0-2-0) and successfully installed it on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04.

The program itself functions like just fine. I can make document classifications and import/export all I want. The only point is that in my configuration I seem to be missing a lot of plugins. Plugins that should be there out-of-the-box as the documentation mentioned. The foremost missing is the CMIS plugin for both export and import. I have found numerous tutorials on how to communicate with Alfresco and others so that is now what I need. I would like to know what I am missing.

BTW: I am aware that the table on the download page states that they are not supported, but that doesn't make them missing, right?

[EDIT]
I have also found the [google code dcma-data-access](https://code.google.com/p/ephesoft/source/browse/trunk/dcma-data-access/?r=9#dcma-data-access%2Fsrc) link, but that does not seem to help either.

Comment: Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the live-chat with Ephesoft I found out that it is **impossible to install** any plugins for the Ephesoft **Community** version. Not supported literally means "can't be installed".

That pretty much answered my question.

Comment: Im doing the exact same thing you are with alfresco and ephesoft only to have this bombshell dropped on my head now regarding CMIS. was wondering where do we go from here? did you find an alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found an alternative to this, other than of course purchasing the Enterprise version. Technically since it was Open Source you could dedicate some time to write your own interface for this. However, it would take considerable knowledge of Java, the Ephesoft framework itself and of course CMIS libraries. Other than that I don't think I have any options.